# Use only part of a php variable - is this possible?

Tags: php

Is it possible to create a new variable with only the left X amount of values automatically?

I have a variable being passed to a page, but I need to use this in a query, both the full variable and part of it

full variable is like this - Day 55

Left of variable - Day

So consequently I would have two variables to use in a query

```
$var1 = "Day 55";

$var2 = "Day";
```

Sorry if this is a noob question, I'm new to php

Comment: give the pattern with more examples

Comment: `$var2 = explode(" ", $var1)[0];` Use explode to split them by the space

Comment: or `list($var2) = explode(' ', $var1);` if you're on a version of PHP lower than 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is the [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)ing.

```
$var1 = "Day 55";
$var2 = substr($var1,0,3); // 3 characters of $var1, starting with character 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

If your variables are always like `Day 55` `Day 35` `Day 7`
then use `explode()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$day = explode(' ',$var1);
```

you will get array:

```
$day[0] //Day
$day[1] //55
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `explode()`;

```
$var = explode(' ', $yourString);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be using the explode function:

```
$arr = explode(" ", $var1);
```

Now the $arr variable contains the values "Day" and "55".

To get the variable "Day", you simply access the array at [0].

```
$var2 = $arr[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var1 = "Day 55";
$tmp=explode(' ', $var1);

$var2=$tmp[0];
$var3=$tmp[1]

//outpu:

$var1="Day 55";
$var2="Day";
$var3="55"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

$var1 = "Day 55";

$var2 = substr($var1, 0, strpos($var1, " "));